# Run Sqoop command on Windows using jar

Tags: database, windows, hadoop, sqoop

I am new to HADOOP hdfs and Sqoop.
I installed hadoop hdfs on one machine with single node. I am able to put and get the file to/from hdfs repectively.

Requirement [Do not want to install hadoop and sqoop on client machine]:
I want to access hdfs from differnt machine using WebHDFS without installation of hadoop on client machine and that part is working fine.

To access HDFF, I am using webhdfs java client jar.
Now I want to execute export/import command of sqoop with remote hdfs.

Case: **Export to local file system where HADOOP as well as Sqoop is not installed, we are using only HADDOP and Sqoop client jar.**

```
public int importToHdfs(String tablename, String stmpPath){
    int resultcode=-1;

    try {
        String s = File.separator;
        String outdir = stmpPath.substring(0,stmpPath.lastIndexOf(s));
        String[] str = {"import"
                , "--connect", jdbcURL
                ,"--table",tablename
                , "--username", sUserName, "--password", sPassword
                , "-m", "1"
                ,"--target-dir","/tmp/user/hduser"
                ,"--outdir",outdir
        };
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        resultcode = Sqoop.runTool(str,conf);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex.toString());
    }
    return resultcode;
}
```